# RabbitMQ - erl.exe high CPU consumption on Windows

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, easynetq

My EC2 instance is consuming 100% CPU after installing RabbitMQ.
Also at times 2 instance of erl.exe are visible in task manager.
I have googled this issue but could not find resolution for it.
I have just started with RabbitMQ and do not have much knowledge on what to check for. Please let me know what should I look for or how to debug.
Any assistance will be of great help.

Memory details :

[image]

Comment: I've seen this behavior only locally on laptops, after coming out of sleep/hibernation. What version of erl/rmq are you running?

Comment: This is running on windows server 2016 (EC2 instance). 

RabbitMQ  Version : 3.7.8  Erlang 21.0.1

Comment: I don't know then unfortunately. I haven't seen this with the latest versions.

Comment: How many CPUs is your EC2 instance configured to have? What EC2 instance type is it?

Comment: It is a free tier EC2 instance with 1 GB RAM, 1 CORE CPU. Also the queue is currently empty.

Comment: I’ve experienced the same issue on my Amazon EC2 instance. It makes using RabbitMQ a no-go for me.

Comment: Same issue here in a locally hosted VM - Intel Xeon 2.60GHz and 4.00 GB RAM